# How can I get to a terminal or virtual console when Ctrl-Alt-F2 fails?

Tags: gnome, xorg, centos

When X and GNOME are working normally, I can just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> to leave GNOME and use the terminal on the second [virtual console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console).  To switch back to GNOME, I can just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Today, X or GNOME stopped working normally for me and I was unable to get to a virtual console.  I was still able to move my mouse cursor around but I wasn't able to click anything.  As far as I could tell, my keyboard was unresponsive, but maybe the right keyboard shortcut would have helped.  I ended up pressing the power button on the computer to gracefully shut it down, but what could I have done to avoid this?

I'm using CentOS 6.0 and GNOME 2.28.

Comment: [F1 and F2 are now ***GUI*** (not text) terminals in Ubuntu 17.10 and later](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157617/reverting-from-ctrl-alt-f1/157621#157621). (For 17.10 (Artful Aardvark), 18.04 (Bionic Beaver), 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish), 19.04 (Disco Dingo), and [19.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)) (Eoan Ermine)). That corresponds to GNOME versions 3.26 - 3.34.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Connecting over the network (e.g. with SSH)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22496/how-can-i-get-to-a-terminal-or-virtual-console-when-ctrl-alt-f2-fails/22499#22499) is by far the method that has the best chance of working and the least chance of causing damage that might otherwise be avoidable (such as killing your X session).

If the mouse is working but not the keyboard, it means that X is not completely hosed. Try plugging the keyboard out and back in: this can help if the problem is in the keyboard driver. (It rarely is.) If you have a root terminal or can get one without the help of the keyboard, try typing `chvt 2` there (where “typing” means copy-pasting the letters).

Another thing you can try is the [magic SysRq key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key): press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to switch the keyboard away from raw mode, and try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> again: this time the key combination should be handled by the kernel and not by X.

Answer (score 5):

Usually I try:

1. to connect using ssh via another host (e.g. I installed `putty` on my mobile phone).
2. to press <kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to kill the **X** session.

Comment: ssh'ing in from another host is a great idea; I used to do this from a computer lab I used to work next to, though this isn't available to me any more.  I'm pretty sure I tried Ctrl-Alt-Backspace to no avail, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

try Alt-SysRq-k to kill the X process, then Alt-SysRq-r to reset the keyboard, then Alt-F2 (not ctrl, since you're back in the kernel keyboard handler not X) to move to other virtual console.

These keys are assigned to their physical locations on a QWERTY keyboard. If you have Dvorak you will need to use different keys.

Comment: No need to start with `Alt+SysRq+K`: sometimes `Alt+SysRq+R` then `Alt+F2` will be enough.